# Trying to create a FAQ with questions and answers from database (MVC Web-Api)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create a FAQ solution with web-API. I'm getting the question and answers from the database. I want only the questions to be shown and the answer to show when the actual question is clicked.

All I get now is every question and answer.

This is my function to get the questions from the database:

```
        function ShowAllFaqs(faqs) {
        var strResult = "<table class='table table-boarded'>";
        $.each(faqs, function (i, p) {
            strResult += "<tr><td>" + p.Question+ "</td></tr>";
            strResult += "<tr><td>" + p.Answer+ "</td><td>" + p.Likes + "</td></tr>";
        });
        strResult += "</table>";
        $("#faqs").html(strResult);
    }
```

and they appear in this div:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <h3>FAQs</h3>
    <div id="faqs"></div>
</div>
```

[This is what i'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMIpG.png)
I want to make something like this, only display questions and when question expand show answer? Anybody know how without new view for the answers

[Here are my index right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnBCJ.png)

[db table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbXhZ.png)

UPDATE:

Now I have this view, is there possible to make the -element hide until you click the  and then show underlying  for each single one?

[Have this now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGIc4.png)

Code for displaying from database in table.

```
        function ShowAllFaqs(faqs) {
        var strResult = "<table class='table table-boarded'>";
        $.each(faqs, function (i, p) {
            strResult += "<tr><th>" + p.Question+ "</th></tr>";
            strResult += "<td>" + p.Answer+ "</td>";
            strResult += "<tr><td>" + "Did this answer you question?" + "</td><tr>";
        });
        strResult += "</table>";
        $("#faqs").html(strResult);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Several methods exists to answer the need, the simplest is the use of DataGrid which can manage the display in Master / Detail mode.
here is a proposal to display the answers in a new page on the click on the button corresponding to the question.

**Javascript Code in the index view**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function ShowAllFaqs(faqs) {
   var strResult = "<table class='table table-boarded'>";
   $.each(faqs, function (i, p) {
   strResult += "<tr><td>" + p.Question+ "</td></tr>";
   strResult += "<tr><td>" + p.Answer+ "</td><td>" + p.Likes + "</td></tr>";
   strResult += "<tr>
            <td> <button type'button' value='Show Answer' onclick='fnGetAnswer('@p.id'); return false;'></button> </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>";   
    });

    strResult += "</table>";
    $("#faqs").html(strResult);

    function fnGetAnswer(idQuestion) {
       window.location.href = '/Answers/GetAnswer?id=' + idQuestion;
       return false;
    }
</script>
```

**The Answer View**

```
@model FAQ.Models.AnswerModel

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Answers";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<body>
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().NumAnswer)
        </th>
        <th>
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Anwser)
        </th>
    </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumAnswer)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Anwser)
                </td>
            </tr>
         }
    </table>                     
</body>
```

**The Answers Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetAnswer(string NumQuestion)
{
    AnswerModel answerModel = GetAnswers (NumQuestion);
    return View(answerModel);
}
```

Cordialy

Comment: Is it possible to do this without a new view. Attached a image of what I'm trying to achieve in original post. Thanks